# CBE Thermal Comfort tool: Error in display of comfort categories?

Tags: simulation

I am a user of the CBE Thermal Comfort tool and I have noticed that the comfort categories are displayed differently according to type of chart (output variables) that is chosen. Specifically for the "Psychrometric chart" vs "Relative Humidity vs air temperature". Please find screenshot attached.

It there something I am missing or is there an error in the display?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for spotting this issue. I will look into it and I will get back to you as soon as posible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. The bug was caused by an error in the calculation of the PMV. In one of the two charts we were not calculating the PMV using the relative airspeed and in the other we were double counting the dynamic clothing insulation.

I believe I have fixed the issue and released a new version of the CBE Thermal Comfort Tool v2.2.0.

Comment: Please have the folks maintaining CBE's website revise the support page to stop pointing people to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site, not a product support site. While the tool itself is open-sourced, the questions being posted here have nothing to do with programming.